# Issues recovering software mirrored drives after installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I wiped my old Windows 7 install, and installed Windows 10. Everything went fine, except my software mirrored volumes did not show up in explorer. I went into Disk Management, and ran a foreign import on them. They are now both showing up as failed. Trying to run "Reactivate Disk" does not work. I have lots of family videos and pics on here, hence the mirror, so I'm really trying not to screw up the data in any way. Any help is appreciated.

Both drives are Toshiba DT01ACA300, and connected via an IOCrest SI-PEX40064

I didn't install any drivers for the SATA card, but I don't remember installing any drivers the first time. The drives are visible from Disk Management, and diskpart.

Here is the data showing in the drive properties. Disk: Disk1 Type: Dynamic Status: Online Partition style: GUID Partition Table Capacity: 2861460 MB Unallocated space: 1MB Reserved space: 0 MB

Disk: Disk 2 (All detailed info is the same as Disk1)

Comment: I've just figured out that Windows 10 does not support Mirroring the same way Windows 7 did. you'll have to temporarily revert back to Windows 7 while you still can.

Comment: Darn, I already wiped the old install.  I'll have to install 7 on a new partition and see if I can extract the data.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem - I've put what I just said into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not handle Mirroring the same way Windows 7 did. You will have to reverse the Windows 10 Update. If you cannot reverse the update, re-install Windows 7, then import the array using Disk Management.

Comment: Man, what a pain!  So much for "upgrading".